# Cloudflare Always Use HTTPS vs adding LetsEncrypt in Nginx

Tags: nginx, digital-ocean, lets-encrypt

Context: I wanted to enable HTTPS support for my API server. It was using Nginx as the reverse proxy server. The [digital ocean documentation](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-nginx-with-let-s-encrypt-on-ubuntu-22-04) suggested to add letsencrypt on the server block.
After I added an A record to the cloudflare DNS, I was able to hit HTTPS for my domain. Because I enabled **Always Use HTTPS** settings from the beginning.

Question: Is it a good practice to just use the **Always Use HTTPS** settings without configuring LetsEncrypt inside Nginx?

Here is my Nginx server block for your reference:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        root /home/sammy/myprojectdir;
    }

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;
    }
}
```